# Livesearch using php and ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a Ajax PHP MySQL live search that basically pulls out manufacturing items from a MySQL database and presents them in a drop-down list, as users enter they search term, one item per line, just like searching in Google.

What I need is a way to allow users to click on a particular link item, and for that to display data on the same page, just below the item(link) clicked.

Any help would be appreciated.

**1.HTML form**

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="javascript:">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchbox1" name="q" token="<?=$csrf->token()?>" action='search1' placeholder="Search for Templates" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default "  id="searchbtn1" type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="livesearch1"></div>
</form>
```

**2. AJAX Call seperate .js file**

```
    $('#searchbox1').on('keyup focus', function(e) {    
        var b = $(this).attr();
        delete b.class, delete b.placeholder, delete b.id, delete b.name, delete b.type, delete b.autocomplete;

        b.q = $(this).val();

        if (b.q != '' && b.q.length > 0) {
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: api,                            
                data: b,
                cache: false,
                success: function(a) {

                    $("#livesearch1").html(a);
                    $("#livesearch1").fadeIn();
                }
            });

        } else {
            $("#livesearch1").fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $('#searchbox1').on('blur', function(e) {

        $('#livesearch1').fadeOut();
    });
```

**3. api call**

```
case 'search':

                 if($app->isAdmin() || $app->isEditor() || $app->isUser())
                {           
                          $app->escape('q');

                          ob_start();

                          ajaxsearch($q);

                          echo $result = ob_get_clean();

                         // json('success','true','results',$result);
                }

            break;
```

**4. .php file**

```
    function ajaxsearch1($q){ 

         $db = MysqliDb::getInstance();
        $csrf = new Csrf_Protect(); 

        $q = removeWhiteSpace($q);
        $q = htmlspecialchars_decode($q,ENT_QUOTES);
        $q = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-. .).(]/', '', $q);

        if(strlen($q) >0 )
        {

          $term = $q; 
          $searchterm = explode(' ',$term);

          $searchColumns = array("name","slug");
          $searchCondition = '';

            for($i = 0; $i < count($searchColumns); $i++)
            {
                $searchFieldName = $searchColumns[$i];
                $searchCondition .= "($searchFieldName LIKE '%" . implode("%' AND $searchFieldName LIKE '%", $searchterm) . "%')";
                if($i+1 < count($searchColumns)) $searchCondition .= " OR ";
            }

            $res = $db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_templates WHERE ($searchCondition) AND (version='1') order by id desc Limit 10 ");

            foreach($res as $sr)
                {  ?><a href="response/<?=$sr['slug']?>" title="<?=ucfirst($sr['name'])?>"><li><?=ucfirst($sr['name'])?></li></a><?php
                }

            }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Check out jQueryUI AutoComplete: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: PS: Especially the API documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ You can specify an Ajax callback as `source` and catch the events when the field is closed or the user selected an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a parameter issue.

data was not in the `$q` it was in the `$name` code should be something like this.

```
case 'search':

     if($app->isAdmin() || $app->isEditor() || $app->isUser())
     {           
         $app->escape('name');
         ob_start();
         ajaxsearch($name);
         echo $result = ob_get_clean();
     }
     break;
```